# Including text when an image/icon is shown

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

At the moment I am trying to include different text when an image and/or icon shows on the page. Here is the code for the vue file:

```
<template>
  <div class="profile">
    <div
      :class="{
        'flags--relevant': hasFlagType('medication'),
        'flags--active': flag == 'medication'
      }"
      class="flags"
      @click="setFlag('medication')"
    >
      <medication-icon
        :class="[
          hasFlagType('medication')
            ? 'medication-icon--focus'
            : 'medication-icon--blur',
        ]"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      :class="{
        'flags--relevant': hasFlagType('condition'),
        'flags--active': flag == 'condition'
      }"
      class="flags"
      @click="setFlag('condition')"
    >
      <treatment-icon
        :class="[
          hasFlagType('condition')
            ? 'treatment-icon--focus'
            : 'treatment-icon--blur',
        ]"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      :class="{
        'flags--relevant': hasFlagType('translator'),
        'flags--active': flag == 'translator',
      }"
      class="flags"
      @click="setFlag('translator')"
    >
      <foreign-dialect-icon
        :class="[
          hasFlagType('translator')
            ? 'foreign-dialect-icon--focus'
            : 'foreign-dialect-icon--blur',
        ]"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  components: {
    ForeignDialectIcon,
    MedicationIcon,
    TreatmentIcon,
  },
  props: {
    userFlags: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flags: this.userFlags,
      flag: null,
      title: "Requires daily medication",
      title2: "Specialist health condition",
      title3: "Requires a translator",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hasFlagType(flagType) {
      return this.flags[flagType] !== undefined;
    },
    setFlag(flagType) {
      if (this.hasFlagType(flagType)) {
        this.flag = flagType;
      }
    },
    resetFlag() {
      this.flag = null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have tried outputting the titles in the data section for each icon and they still show even if the icon doesn't show. I need it to output the title when the image is shown and the many attempts I've tried haven't worked so was wondering how I am able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the title should only appear when the corresponding icon is focused, you could use the same condition (`hasFlagType(...)`) with `v-if` to render the `title`:

```html
<div>
  <medication-icon .../>
  <span v-if="hasFlagType('medication')">{{ title }}</span>
</div>
<div>
  <treatment-icon .../>
  <span v-if="hasFlagType('condition')">{{ title2 }}</span>
</div>
<div>
  <foreign-dialect-icon .../>
  <span v-if="hasFlagType('translator')">{{ title3 }}</span>
</div>
```